# How to save Flutter TextFormField user input to a value?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to learn Flutter and I'm confused.

I want to make a super simple text form and a button. The user enters text into the form, clicks the button, and the text prints to the console. How hard could this be? :-)

```java
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() => runApp(const Kabbalah());

class Kabbalah extends StatelessWidget {
  const Kabbalah({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Kabbalistic Numerology';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text(_title),
          ),
          body: const Center(
            child: const FullNameField(),
          )
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FullNameField extends StatefulWidget {
  const FullNameField({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _FullNameState();
  }
}

class _FullNameState extends State<FullNameField> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8, vertical: 16),
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Enter your full name (First Middle Last)',
            ),
            onSaved: (String? fullName) {
              debugPrint(fullName);
              // This optional block of code can be used to run
              // code when the user saves the form.
            },
          ),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
          onPressed: () {
            debugPrint('Clicked!');
            setState(() {
              _FullNameState.save(); // <-- problem is here
            });
          },
          child: const Text('Get Fortune'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

My code makes a nice little form and an adorable button.

[image]

When enter a name and click the button I see `Clicked!` in the console.

My plan is that after the user clicks the button we save the form state. Then `onSaved()` will execute and print the entered text to the console.

The problem seems to be in saving the form state after the user clicks the button. `_fullNameState.save();` doesn't work because `_fullNameState` doesn't have a `.save` member. Don't we get `.save` from extending `StatefulWidget`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done your work. I have attached my Code Snippets below. Please check and try yourself. Hope it will help. I also attached Screenshots below.

main.dart Code Snippet -->>

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test2/test3.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: TextFormFieldWidgetTest.id,
      routes: {
        TextFormFieldWidgetTest.id: (context) => TextFormFieldWidgetTest(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

TextForm Field Code -->

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TextFormFieldWidgetTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFormFieldWidgetTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static final String id = "text_form_field";

  @override
  _TextFormFieldWidgetTestState createState() =>
      _TextFormFieldWidgetTestState();
}

class _TextFormFieldWidgetTestState extends State<TextFormFieldWidgetTest> {
  // * Form Key
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  // * Editing Controller
  final TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();

  String? firstName;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: const Color(0x0fffffff),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "First Name",
                        floatingLabelStyle: const TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF1cbb7c),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade500,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            width: 1,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            width: 2,
                            color: Color(0xFF1cbb7c),
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        contentPadding:
                            const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 15, 20, 15),
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                      ),
                      controller: firstNameController,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        firstNameController.text = value!;
                      },
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      firstName = firstNameController.text;
                      print(firstName);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text("Save Data"),
                ),
                firstName == null ? Text("") : Text(firstName!),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Before Putting Text Value -->>
[image]

After Putting Text Value -->>
[image]

Comment: Thanks! People like you make StackOverflow wonderful.

Comment: It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use a TextEditingController?

just initialise one like this:

```
TextEditingController yourController = TextEditingController();
```

and then use it in the textformfield:

```
controller: yourController;
```

when the button is clicked, you execute:

```
String enteredText = yourController.text();
print(enteredText);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController tc = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          controller: tc,
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
            child: Text("Print"),
            onPressed: () {
              print(tc.text);
              Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
                tc.clear();
              });
            }),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
 }
```

Now, we are using TextEditingController here because it gives control to the parent widget over its child state. [To know more](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html#:%7E:text=A%20controller%20for%20an%20editable,the%20controller%20notifies%20its%20listeners.&text=A%20TextEditingController%20can%20also%20be,value%20for%20a%20text%20field.)

Now, .text Contains the value entered in the TextField. So, when the button is pressed the value is printed and the form is cleared.